# how to query teststep from testcase in Rally java api

Tags: java, rally

I can able to fetch testcase results which contains testcase name and other details . But i couldn't get test step for a testcase . My query contains steps attribute which has teststep url associate with it . is there a way where i can fetch teststep details for a testcase

```
  //create new QueryRequest
 QueryRequest tests = new QueryRequest("Test Case");

 tests.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name","Owner","Test Folder","steps","LastRun"));

  // Query Rally
  QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(tests);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you just need to make a second request to hydrate the steps for each test case in question.

You can check out this example here, which is defects on a story:

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/blob/master/src/main/resources/examples/com/rallydev/rest/CollectionQueryExample.java

Comment: Thank you , i did not know we can pass JsonObject as Query String ... It worked ....